# SCA Webstore Session Bugs

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

We experience session bugs in our SCA website (Mont Blanc).

The session bugs are:

- you are logged in but sometimes the website still shows the 'login | register' link. Ie, it doesn't recognise you as logged in.
- you click the login/register link intending to login but you get taken to the checkout page

Have other SCA developers experienced this bug (SCA is known for many) and what have you done to fix this? Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is there, We are changing our version to Elburs

Answer (score 0):

Being sent to checkout upon logging in is due to the SSP application's touchpoints missing parameters. Specifically, the checkout.ssp is used for login, checkout, and register. By default, it handles checkout, but with a parameter of `is=login` or `is=register`, it will go to the appropriate places after login is complete.

[image]

I'm not sure offhand the solution for the first question.